# UIActivityViewController Error: Failed to determine whether URL is managed by a file provider

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

I record a video in my app and write it it to the temp directory to allow the user to share it through UIActivityViewController. The video can successfully be played back in-app, and through UIActivityViewController can successfully be sent through Messages, shared to Facebook, and saved to camera roll. But when I try to share through WhatsApp, I get the following error:

`Failed to determine whether URL /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E7F57458-A5F9-44CB-86FA-ACC4309C7473/tmp/65CB72B3-373E-42F2-8A80-9888E00C2268.mp4 (n) is managed by a file provider`

I have been unable to find much information on this error. Does anyone know why this may be occurring?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: did you found a solution ?

Comment: @karmous unfortunately not - I put it on hold for now

Comment: @karmous Found the fix - posted below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a fix:

I was opening a UIActivityViewController with the video url and a string as the `activityItems`. Passing just the video url fixed the issue of WhatsApp not recognizing the video. It's annoying to not be able to pass in the text, but at least the video is now there.

**Does not work:**

`UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url, "Check out my video!"], applicationActivities: nil)`

**Does Work:**

`UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error. What happens, actually - every app run the path to the file is not the same but **I don't remember why** I save not just the name of the file - but the whole path. Reasonable when I try to read it - I'll get nothing. Example - if I save the file each app run:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1265C296-F2B1-44D6-AD3D-6F2DD59557D3/Documents/what.jpeg
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2B53592-B327-48E9-BF70-BE2826022271/Documents/what.jpeg
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2505B73F-27EF-4B5C-8D21-EB49A45ABE99/Documents/what.jpeg
```

Right practice - use **Document folder** path from `FileManager`, you can found more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47071603/1067147)

```
+ (NSURL *)getDocumentsDirectoryPath {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask]lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I ran my app on the Simulator. However it was working as expected when I ran the app on a real device.