# Failed to determine whether URL is managed by a file provider

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Since two days I have this problem

I tried a lot,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764198/10392572

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457518/10392572

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51218715/10392572

If I'm right, UIActivityViewController need an array of url(s) of the file(s) and documentInteractionController need an url and both ask user what he want do, but every time, if the user use "save to file" I have:

> [default] [ERROR] Failed to determine whether URL /Users/lukashedinger/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/45A185C5-6DEA-4A52-B415-939758FB7F7E/data/Containers/Data/Application/D4E32740-958D-43A6-BEC1-EECEB8CF732D/tmp/Vitalstoffwerte 22092018-22092018.pdf (n) is managed by a file provider

Anyone have idea if there is other way to ask user, where he want save a file or what I can do with my error?

Her is my code in short, perhaps something is wrong?

```
    let dateiName = "Vitalstoffwerte " + heuteString
    let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(dateiName).pdf"

    pdfData.write( toFile: path, atomically: true)

    let fileUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

------- UPDATE : Found a way for my problem, but not for file -----

I've given the pdfData direct to ViewController, haven't saved it to file.

UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData], applicationActivities: nil)

I'm not using a file and that is good enough for me

-- UPDATE --

My new idea is that first try to save the file and try it's URL, and if this fails, then use the pdfData directly, because in some simulator using URL gives no error and in other gives error.

More here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499637/10392572

Comment: The path you pass to the `UIActivityViewController` should be to a file that already exists. Do you actually have that specific PDF file before showing the activity controller?

Comment: I think yes, because I try it with other file. Someone say to me, that I can not use a url. He say, perhaps i can use a Trapper of Typ UIActivityItemProvider  or a own class with UIActivityItemSource Protokoll.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Simulator. But when I tried it on a real device it was working as expected.